# AttributeError: module 'keras.api._v2.keras' (resolved)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, error-handling, google-colaboratory

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
!pip install --upgrade numpy
!pip install --upgrade tensorflow==2.14.0
import tensorflow as tf

tf.__version__
print("Keras version: {}".format(tf.keras.__version__))
#print("TensorFlow version: {}".format(tf.__version__))

print("Eager execution: {}".format(tf.executing_eagerly()))

tf.keras.__version__
```

it gives error in google colab like this,ıts python.what could reason of that error.what could ı do?

```
 AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-e0388c33abd4> in <cell line: 9>()
      7 
      8 tf.__version__
----> 9 print("Keras version: {}".format(tf.keras.__version__))
     10 #print("TensorFlow version: {}".format(tf.__version__))
     11 

AttributeError: module 'keras.api._v2.keras' has no attribute '__version__'
```

I resolved problem by installing 1.9.3 version of scipy (and uninstalled old version), cause scikit-learn depends on at least scipy 1.5.0. Please write your code in new code cell and do comment other installing code(already installed,at first run) on google colab

Comment: for tf.keras, it would be only tf.__version__

Comment: keeps giving the same error @Innat

Comment: check with pip list, see is there any package conflict (tf.keras or only keras).